# Como obter o percentil de uma soma no Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma tabela no Postgres que possui dados diários de chuva. Como posso obter o percentil da soma anual de chuva ao longo dos anos?

A tabela que tenho é como esta:

| Data | Chuva |
| --- | --- |
| 01/02/2020 | 4.2 |
| 02/02/2020 | 2.3 |
| 03/02/2020 | 3.7 |
| ... | ... |
| 01/03/2020 | 2.1 |
| 02/03/2020 | 3.8 |

Estou tentando usar algumas variações de `SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY chuvas.chuva) FROM chuvas;` com `SUM(chuva)` mas não tive sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um subselect dentro do **PERCENTILE_CONT**. Seria algo como:

```
SELECT percentile_cont(0.25) WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY chv.soma_chuvas ) 
FROM (SELECT data_chuva, sum(chuva) as soma_chuva  FROM chuvas  GROUP BY data_chuva) as chv
```